# Printing in Order and Reverse Order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

The following code needs to print the random numbers in the array in order and reverse order. I have the reverse order printing but for some reason I can't seem to get it to print in original order. I'm not sure what to modify. What I currently have prints out a blank line for the "in order" and the numbers for "reverse order". What do I need to fix? Thank you!

```
public class RandomPrintOut
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   // 
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

       int numbers[] = new int [10]; 

       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
       { 
       numbers [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 100); 
       }



      System.out.println ("The size of the array: " + numbers.length);

      System.out.println ("The numbers in order:");

      for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++)
          System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");

      System.out.println ("\nThe numbers in reverse order:");

      for (int index = numbers.length-1; index >= 0; index--)
         System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Check the boundaries of your `for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++)`. Hint: check the first `for` loop in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the code below:

```
for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++)
```

Here the initialized value for `index` is **number.length+1**, this value is **`10+1=11`**.  **This is greater than 10, as a result, the codition is never satisfied in this for-loop. That's why the array is not printed in order.**

You need to do the change as follows:

Frome

```
for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++)
      System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
```

to

```
for (int index = 0; index <10; index++)
        System.out.print(numbers[index] + "  ");
```

**Code after change is as follows:**

public class RandomPrintOut
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   // 
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

```
   int numbers[] = new int [10]; 

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
   { 
   numbers [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 100); 
   }

  System.out.println ("The size of the array: " + numbers.length);

  System.out.println ("The numbers in order:");

  for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
      System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");

  System.out.println ("\nThe numbers in reverse order:");

  for (int index = numbers.length-1; index >= 0; index--)
     System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
```

}
}

**An result output printed in Console:**

```
The size of the array: 10
The numbers in order:
31  50  49  99  29  54  41  16  7  21  
The numbers in reverse order:
21  7  16  41  54  29  99  49  50  31
```

Comment: Why to do that change? What's the difference when using it in the former instead of the latter?

Comment: Oh wow. I had that but I had index <=10 instead. That seems to make all the difference

Comment: In such for-loop for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++). Here the initialized value for index is number.length+1, this value is 10+1=11. This is greater than 10, as a result, the codition is never satisfied in this for-loop. That's why the array is not printed in order.

Comment: @Lou44 The difference is mainly in the starting index. Also, *please* do not hard code the range of the loop as has been done here. Use `index < numbers.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the values of `index` over this loop

```
  for (int index = numbers.length+1; index <= 10; index++)
      System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
```

Try doing it by hand and see what it looks like. That should help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RandomPrintOut {
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   // 
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args) {

       int numbers[] = new int [10]; 

       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) { 
       numbers [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 100); 
       }



      System.out.println ("The size of the array: " + numbers.length);

      System.out.println ("The numbers in order:");

      for (int index = 0; index <= numbers.length-1; index++) {
          System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
      }

      System.out.println ("\nThe numbers in reverse order:");

      for (int index = numbers.length-1; index >= 0; index--) {
         System.out.print (numbers[index] + "  ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: C'mon, don't hard code the `10`. Also, if OP can just copy-paste he/she will not learn.

Comment: Good, keep just giving OP the code to make it work without any explanation about the problem and the solution, surely OP will learn by him/herself and stop asking about this when encountering with the same problem in the future (that may be possibly in few days from here).

Comment: @Zong and Luiggi: Agreed. But thought it was too simple to explain and he/she will realize it after just reading the code...